# Trying to build a String using recursion in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm trying to build the following string using recursion in **Java**. The expected output is:

> 4! = 4!
>   = 4 * 3!
>   = 4 * 3 * 2!
>   = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1!
>   = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 0!

This is my factorial method:

```
public static String factorial(int n, int count, String equation) 
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return equation += (n + "!");
    } else {
        equation += (n - count);
        return factorial(n - 1, count, equation);
    }
}
```

I'm entering the following input in my `main` method:

```
System.out.print(factorial(4, 0, ""));
```

It currently prints out the String "43210!" I haven't worked with recursion much. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output for the call `System.out.print(factorial(4, 0, ""));`

Comment: `equation += (n - count);` you aren't building the rest of the statement into your string - you're just adding a number (like `4`) when you want something like (`4 + `

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve with this factorial program. But mathematically, n! equates to `n X (n-1)  X ... 1`. E.g. 4! = 4 X 3 X 2 X 1. However you are doing 4 + 3 + 2 + 1.

Comment: @VHS changed the addition operators to multiplication. That's my mistake!

Comment: @KevinL I tried doing that, and it gives me the output stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some your code,then code can achieve one's goals.here is the code.I hope this can help you.

```
public class Snippet {
    public static String factorial(int n, String equation) 
    {
        if (n == 0) {
            return equation += (n + "!");
        } else {
            equation += (n + "*");
            return factorial(n - 1, equation);
        }
    }

    public static void factorial1(int n, String equation) 
    {
        if(n < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(equation + n + "!");
        factorial1(n - 1, equation + n + "*");
    }

    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        System.out.println("4! ");
        System.out.println(factorial(4, "="));
        System.out.println();
        factorial1(4, "=");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve your goal using only one recursion function, it will require **nested recursion**. You might want to try something like following:

```
public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(4));
    }

    private static String factorial(int origNum, int lineNum, int innerLoopNum, String equation) {      
        if(innerLoopNum == origNum - lineNum) {
            equation = equation + innerLoopNum + "!" + "\n";
        }
        else  if(lineNum > origNum)
            return equation;
        else {
            equation = equation + innerLoopNum + "*";
            equation = factorial(origNum, lineNum, --innerLoopNum, equation);
            return equation;
        }

        ++lineNum;
        if(lineNum > origNum)
            return equation;

        return factorial(origNum, lineNum, origNum, equation);      
    }

    public static String factorial(int n) {
        return factorial(n, 0, n, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *n* will never be negative, this should suffice...

```
public String factorialString(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return "0!";
    return n + " * " + factorialString(n - 1);
}
```

Just for fun, you can also write it as:

```
public String factorialString(int n) {
    return (n == 0) 
       ? "0!"
       : n + " * " + factorialString(n - 1);
}
```

---

For people concerned, I know I am doing a string concatenation and I should use a StringBuilder instead. The task is to demonstrate recursion here.